# If I renounce my nationality to get Japanese passport, what will I put next time I have to fill the nationality field

Tags: japan, stateless-persons

To acquire Japanese passport, the foreign national has to renounce his/her nationality. In such case, what will that person put in the nationality field as in many cases filling up the nationality field in mandatory. For instance, yesterday I was filling the online Transit visa application for Srilanka and there the nationality field is marked as a required field.

If I renounce my nationality and Japan doesn't give me nationality, will I be considered stateless?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you mean that you have to renounce your non-Japanese nationality before you know for sure that you'll get Japanese nationality (such as before applying)?

Comment: Generally something like renouncing existing citizenships is among the last steps you would take. States don't like making people stateless. That you would have to do so, without knowing if you will be granted citizenship of Japan seems very very unlikely. Furthermore, your existing country of citizenship may not even recognise the renunciation, so check there.

Comment: I want to apply for Japanese passport but according to the rules, one cannot hold the nationality of any other country, if he/she want to acquire Japanese passport. My concern is, if I renounce my current nationality what should I put in the nationality field next time, I have fill up a form.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Japanese nationality law, but I expect that at the point of application you would be asked to confirm your willingness to do so, rather than actually renounce the citizenship (which would happen at a later date).

Comment: The answer to your final question is going to depend on your existing nationality, for example the UK officially takes back the renunciation if you haven't received a new citizenship 6 months after giving it up. https://www.gov.uk/renounce-british-nationality/after-youve-applied

Comment: I would be very surprised if having Japanese citizenship were not a requirement to obtain the passport. "Renounce all other citizenships" to me means " while keeping the Japanese". A Google search does seem to agree that one must be a Japanese citizen to get the passport.

Comment: You seem to be conflating "getting a passport" and "getting citizenship". Are you already a Japanese citizen (in this case, a dual citizen of both Japan and another country) and just want to get a passport, or are you a citizen of another country, and want to become a citizen of Japan? If the latter, under what rules? Marriage, naturalisation...?

Comment: Also, many countries just won't allow you to renounce your nationality if you don't already have another or are quite advanced in the process to get another, precisely to avoid creating stateless persons. And some countries just won't let you.

Comment: It's very bad idea to leave Japan during the year needed to get citizenship. Even changing job is not recommended. So, that's "solves" the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a notary in the US and once did a notarization for a woman who had a Japanese passport and a US passport; both were in force at the time I met her (around 5 years ago). Perhaps the rules have changed, or perhaps it depends on the circumstances of the person applying for the passport. You should probably consult an immigration lawyer.

Comment: The rules may be different for people who are dual nationals by right (through their parents, through their place of birth, through marriage in some countries...) and those who want to acquire the citizenship (naturalisation after having spent a number of years in the country, for instance).